# How to call a ruby script from webpage and output the results?

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Okay so maybe you guys can advise me. Here is what I am attempting to do.

1. I am trying to call my ruby script from a html form on a website that has already been created.
2. The form needs to pass a variable entered in a text box to the ruby script.
3. Once the script is finished (it's doing a sql query) it needs to output the results to the webpage.

What do you guys think this is the best way to go about doing this? I looked at Rails but the webpage is already created and I don't want to create full scale webapp. I also looked at Rack, but I am not sure if that is the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby code is executed in a RVM (MRI, JRUBY, etc). It is served by a Webserver(NGINX, Apache, etc) which processes it by a RVM WebServer stack(CGI/Phussion Passenger) and passes it through Ruby middleware (Rack)  and associated frameworks (Sinatra, Rails, etc).

Some WebServers have RVM Stacks built into them Puma, Unicorn, etc.

Using nginx to proxy-pass a specific request path from a url to a RVM enabled webstack + sinatra app would work fine. You might include the uri/pages as an iframe to inject into your current server as well.

A simple example of exposing a sinatra app running in a rvm unicorn stack through nginx.

https://github.com/p8952/nginx-unicorn-sinatra